# Creating a variable column table model in MVC

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc

I have the following table:

```
        | Math  | English | Chemistry
John J. |  A    |    F    |     B
Mike M. |  A    |    F    |     B
Eve E.  |  A    |    F    |     B
```

So I have a variable number of columns (can be set up at run time) and a variable number of students.

My SQL DB **can** look like:

```
Table 1
  studentID
  studentName
  studentAddress
```

---

```
Table 2:
  disciplineID
  disciplineName
  disciplineTeacher
```

---

```
Table 3:
  studentID
  disciplineID
  grade
```

How should my model look like? Can I do something like:

```
public class Catalog
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<Discipline> Disciplines { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<Grades> StudentGrades { get; set; }
}

internal class Discipline
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

internal class Student
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

internal class Grades
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public int DisciplineId { get; set; }
    public char Grade { get; set; }
}
```

Is this the normal way to do this multi-column/run-time definition?
How can I ensure the disciplines are always in the same order in the view?
How can I ensure that in the view, when I render the table row, for each student the correct Grade is displayed for the correct Discipline?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this the normal way to do this multi-column/run-time definition?

It's not the only way, but (to me) doesn't seem anything wrong with passing all the separate data to the view and let the view sort it out.

You could convert to an ILookup by student - this would reduce the code in the view.

> How can I ensure the disciplines are always in the same order in the view?

You've not included what you've tried so far.

Essentially: Loop through each student, then loop through each discipline and find the corresponding grade for each - if there isn't one, display a "-"

Something like: you should use @Html.DisplayFor etc

```
<tbody>
   @foreach(var student in Model.Students)
   {
     <tr>
       <td>@student.Name</td>
       @foreach(var discipline in Model.Disiplines)
       {
          var grade = Model.Grades.Where(
                           x => x.StudentId == student.StudentId 
                                && x.DisciplineId == discipline.DisciplineId)
                            .FirstOrDefault();
          <td>
              @(grade==null ? "-" : grade.Grade)
          </td>
       }
     </tr>
   }
```

Comment: My biggest problem with this approach is that I lose the database support. Instead of me doing the manual search, I would prefer to let the DB do this, because of indexes, optimizations, etc.

Comment: After your comment, the Catalog would look like this:  
    public class Catalog2
    {  
        public int ID { get; set; }  
        public virtual IEnumerable<Discipline> Disciplines { get; set; }  
        public virtual ILookup<string /*studentName*/, ILookup<string /*disciplineName*/, Grades>> StudentGrades { get; set; }  
    }

Comment: That would imply the student had multiple grades for the same discipline.  `ILookup<int /*studentid*/, IDictionary<int /*disciplineid*/, char grade>>`.   Always link on IDs as there may be two students with the same name.  If you want to load from the DB then create a view and matching class.